# why android webview pageDown() method returns false?

Tags: android, webview

why android webview pageDown(boolean value) method returns false? what are the reasons?

Answer (score 1):

It returns false if the event related to page down was not handled.

Comment: yeah i know that one but what is the reason? if i scroll manually i could able to scroll up to end...why so?

Comment: A possible solution to the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047134/pagedowntrue-always-returning-false-in-webview-android/12133511#12133511