# pageDown(true) always returning false in WebView Android

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView in Android which stores a conversation stream for my application.

Every 20 seconds the app polls a server for any messages and updates the WebView.

Each time the WebView updates it scrolls back to the top of the view.

I wanted to stop this happening so I tried using the webView.pageDown(true); but this always seems to be returning false.

Any help would be really appreciated.  Here is the code:

```
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
    boolean scrolled = webView.pageDown(true);
    System.out.println("Scrolled is: " + scrolled);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so investigated further and found these releated here:

- [why android webview pageDown() method returns false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644346/why-android-webview-pagedown-method-returns-false)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064622/fix-scrollbar-to-bottom-of-web-view-in-android

The only solution I manage to come up with is to create a handler that will delay the call for webView.pageDown(true) for 100ms, and then it works. It might need less or more time, probably dependent on the time the web view component needs to render the given html.

Here is the code for load and scroll:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
mWebViewScrollHandler.removeCallbacks(mScrollWebViewTask);
mWebViewScrollHandler.postDelayed(mScrollWebViewTask, 100);
```

Here is the code for the handler:

```
private final Handler mWebViewScrollHandler = new Handler();    

private final Runnable mScrollWebViewTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        webView.pageDown(true);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`loadDataWithBaseURL` is asynchronous so `pageDown` will be executed before the page finished loading. That's why @ZoltanF said it would need to wait for some time before executing the code

You need to add listener to the page loading and then do scrolling:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override  
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        webView.pageDown(true);
    }  
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm yet to test this but it seems like a viable explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for this problem:

Instead of reloading the `WebView`, change the web page on the server so that it updates itself using ajax. This will give more control on the behavior.

On a different approach, use event listeners as Sean mentioned:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override  
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        webView.pageDown(true);
    }  
});
```